# Why this doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, wrapper

```
var str="Hello World!"; 
var patt=/\x57/g;
var matched = str.match(patt);
document.write(matched.strike());
```

It seems that the problem is `matched.strike()`. With `matched` only it works. So why?

Comment: What are you expecting? `Array#strike` is not a built-in method. Have you defined it somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.strike()` method operates on strings and `matched` is an array.  You must dereference the first match to see the correct output.

```
var str="Hello World!"; 
var patt=/\x57/g;
var matched = str.match(patt);
// Access first element of the matched array
document.write(matched[0].strike());

// Or via .pop() or .shift()
document.write(matched.pop().strike());
// or
document.write(matched.shift().strike());
// either returns "<strike>W</strike>"
```

The [`String.strike()` method is nonstandard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/strike), and should not be relied upon for complete browser support.

Comment: … furthermore, it’s non-standard.

Comment: `String.strike` is a built-in method?  What does it do?

Comment: @RocketHazmat — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/strike

Comment: @Quentin: Cool, didn't know about that :-P

Comment: I'm totally gonna start relying upon `String.blink` :-P

Comment: @RocketHazmat `function marquee(str) {return str.blink();}`

Comment: Furthermore, try not to use `document.write`, as it will clear the entire page.  You should use `appendChild` to add DOM elements.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: In fact, it looks like [a specification](http://mathias.html5.org/specs/javascript/#string.prototype.strike) is being set up for those functions...

Comment: @pimvdb Oh, interesting. Though, IMHO? Utterly stupid. Is there also `String#span`, `String#spanWithClassBig` and `String#spanWithClassMyCustomClass`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph That's what I imagine WordPress would do if it built its own JS library...

Answer (score 1):

The (very old) `strike` method is a `String` method. `RegExp.match` returns an `Array` which doesn't know a `strike` method.

Your code could be rewritten to:

```
var str = 'Hello World'.replace(/\x57/g,function(s){return s.strike();});
//=> Hello <strike>W</strike>orld
```